# Flex: Sending parameters to Alert closeHandler

Tags: apache-flex, parameters, alert, send

Is it possible to send parameters to a closeHandler Alert function?
The fisrt parameter the function gets is the CloseEvent, but how to send another one?

```
<s:Button id="btnLoadLocalData" label="Load data"
          click="Alert.show('Populate list with local data?', '', Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, this, loadLocalData(???parameters???), null, Alert.OK);"/>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be possible using Flex's dynamic function construction. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426540/how-to-create-custom-mouseevent-click-event-in-as3-pass-parameters-to-function).

Here's an example:

**The parameters and handler:**

```
var parameters:String = "Some parameter I want to pass";

private function loadLocalData(e:Event, parameter:String):void
{
  // voila, here's your parameter
}

private function addArguments(method:Function, additionalArguments:Array):Function 
{
  return function(event:Event):void {method.apply(null, [event].concat(additionalArguments));}
}
```

**Your component:**

```
<s:Button id="btnLoadLocalData" label="Load data"
          click="Alert.show('Populate list with local data?', '', Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, this, addArguments(loadLocalData, [parameters])), null, Alert.OK);"/>
```

Comment: Just what I needed! I want to reduce the number of handler functions as much as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

An approach might be to create the closeHandler in the scope of the alert creation.

Here's an example:

```
<s:Button id="btnLoadLocalData" label="Load data" click="btnLoadLocalData_clickHandler(event)"/>

function btnLoadLocalData_clickHandler(event:Event):void {
  var someVar:Object = someCalculation();
  var closeHandler:Function = function(closeEvent:CloseEvent):void {
    // someVar is available here
  };
  Alert.show('Populate list with local data?', '', Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, this, closeHandler, null, Alert.OK);
}
```

Comment: Awesome use of closure and scope to pull of a much needed trick quite nicely

Answer (score 10):

My typical method of handling this use case is to add the data to the Alert form.  For example

```
var o:Object = new Object();
o["stuff"] = "quick brown fox";

var alert:Alert = Alert.show("Message", "Title", mx.controls.Alert.YES | mx.controls.Alert.NO, null, OnAlertResult);
alert.data = o;
```

And then in the close handler for the Alert

```
private function OnAlertResult(event:CloseEvent):void {
    trace(event.target.data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use an anonymous function to wrap a function call with parameters:

```
Alert.show("Are you sure?", Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, null, function(event:CloseEvent):void{doSomething(event.detail, param1, param2);}, null, Alert.CANCEL)
```