# changing the scope of an anonymous function on a setTimeout causes a weird warning

Tags: javascript, scope

this has interested me purely as research and personal development. i have a namespaced set of functions / variables.

within 1 function I need to call another through setTimeout but keeping the scope to 'this'. i am struggling with this a little, can't seem to bind it for when the setTimeout runs.

```
var foo = {
    ads: ["foo","bar"],
    timeDelay: 3,
    loadAds: function() {
        var al = this.ads.length;
            if (!al)
                return; // no ads

            for(var i = 0; i < al; i++) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.scrollAd(this.ads[i]);
                }.apply(this), this.timeDelay * 1000);
            }
        },
        scrollAd: function(adBlock) {
            console.log(adBlock);

        }
    };
};
```

the .apply(this) DOES change the scope as the console.log outputs the right object back, but it runs the function immediately and then the exception/warning comes up as the callback remains empty:

```
useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
```

is there an elegant way of doing this at all? i know i could do

```
var _this = this;
```

and reference `_this` in the anon callback. for example, in mootools i'd use `.bind(this)` instead...

and no, as this involves animating, i don't want to use `" "` around the string as it will need to be eval'd and would impact performance...

Comment: OK just see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224847/declare-variable-in-another-scope/19333647#19333647

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < al; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.scrollAd(this.ads[i]);
    }.apply(this), this.timeDelay * 1000);
}
```

`apply` doesn't bind a function, it calls it. So you execute the scroll straight away and then pass its return value (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`, which is ineffective.

You probably meant to use a closure like this over `this` and the loop variable (which must be closed or it will be the same, post-loop value for every timeout):

```
for(var i = 0; i < al; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(that, j) {
        return function() {
            that.scrollAd(that.ads[j]);
        };
    }(this, i), this.timeDelay * 1000);
}
```

However you may prefer to use the new ECMAScript Fifth Edition function binding feature, which has a much more compact syntax:

```
for (var i= 0; i<al; i++)
    setTimeout(this.scrollAd.bind(this, this.ads[i]), this.timeDelay*1000);
```

(There's an implementation of `function.bind` for browsers that don't have have it natively at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748941/setattribute-onclick-and-cross-browser-compatability#749253).)

Comment: yeah cool. this .bind prototype works fine, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know you should indeed use something like this:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){self.scrollAd(ad);}, this.timeDelay * 1000);
```

But if you badly want to use `.apply()`, then do it like this:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    function(){
    }.apply(self);
}, this.timeDelay * 1000);
```

Also note that if you run this inside a `for` loop and use `i`'s value inside a function that is run in timer, then your function will always run with the last value of `i` (i.e. `i == al`). In order to fix that, you'll need to make a closure with each value of `i` separately.

So taking your code and making it work it should look like this:

```
var foo = {
    ads: ["foo","bar"],
    timeDelay: 3,
    loadAds: function() {
        function runTimed(o, fn, args, time)
        {
            setTimeout(function(){ fn.apply(o, args); }, time);
        }
        var al = this.ads.length;
            if (!al)
                return; // no ads

            for(var i = 0; i < al; i++) {
                runTimed(this, this.scrollAd, this.ads[i], this.timeDelay*1000);
            }
        },
        scrollAd: function(adBlock) {
            console.log(adBlock);
        }
    };
};
```

**Note:** I haven't run this code so it may contain some mistakes.

Also if I were you, I'd use the data from object and don't pass it to the `scrollAd` (`i` is enough).

Comment: erm, yeah missed the iteration issue with the i there, reverted to using forEach as a custom prototype iterator. cheers!