# Declare variable in another scope

Tags: javascript

Look at this snipped code:

```
main = function() {
  alert('This is ' + T);
}

caller = function() {
  var T = 'me';
  main();
}

caller();
```

as you see, I wanna function main identify the value of variable T, but the browser appears this error: T is undefined.

I can handle this error with change the scope of variable T to global scope or even pass the T variable to function main, but for some reason I don't want to use those and I want to declare variable T in scope of function main. Is it possible or not? How can I handle this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be really interested to know what that "some reason" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this can handle it.

```
main = function() {
  alert('This is ' + T);
}

caller = function() {
  var T = 'me';
  eval('var func = ' + main);
  func();
}

caller();
```

Comment: …er, no. If you need to do things like this, your structure is atrocious.

Comment: what do you mean about your structure is atrocious, what's the pros and cons?

Comment: I don't know what your structure actually is, but using `eval` this way is a "code smell" which almost always indicates a bad structure (not to mention that it kills performance in modern browsers). Besides that, you're evaluating the string representation of a function, which could lead to all sorts of odd bugs (it's not a common thing). You've already been given a lot of perfectly valid suggestions on how you could be doing this in a much better way (see JaredPar's answer for example). If they're not applicable to your situation, you need to restructure. Hence my first comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is that I can't put main and caller function in the same scope each others are belonging to specific class, I am wondering that how can I declare a local variable in another function's scope. is it possible? or what do Javascript's interpreter do when encounter the var word. can I do something like this without use of var word.

Comment: "each others are belonging to specific class": Then if you are trying to pass variables between (without using parameters or setters/getters) then it is a clear sign of bad structure. You should put some time into fixing the overall structure, not trying to figure out strange corner-cases of the language. It will save you a lot of time (especially bug-fixing time) in the long-run. It sounds to me like a setter/getter is the solution in your case, but without seeing more code I couldn't say. Try posting a more comprehensive view of your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I just snipped code and the url is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32637/define-local-variable-in-function

Answer (score 6):

You have 3 options:

- to declare T outside both
- to pass T to main(T) as a parameter
- to write main inside caller

Answer (score 3):

`T` is a local variable to `caller` so it will not be visible inside `main`, one easy solution is to pass `T` as a parameter to `caller` from `main`

you need to pass `T` as a parameter

```
main = function(T) {
  alert('This is ' + T);
}

caller = function() {
  var T = 'me';
  main(T);
}

caller();
```

Another solution is to declare `T` in a shared scope, this this case the global scope or declare `main` as a closure function inside `main`

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you have a few options beside the obvious ones you have already stated.

One way is to declare main in caller:

```
caller = function() {
  var T = 'me',
      main = function() {
        alert('This is ' + T);
      };
  main();
}

caller();
```

An other case would be to wrap both caller and main into an object, but that could be overkill. Still another way could be to set the `this` variable using `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
main = function() {
  alert('This is ' + this);
}

caller = function() {
  var T = 'me';
  main.call(T);
}

caller();
```

Or

```
main = function() {
  alert('This is ' + this);
}

caller = function() {
  var T = 'me',
      newMain = main.bind(T);
      newMain();
}

caller();
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to define a new function which declares `T`, `main` and `caller`.  This way both functions have access to the value but it is not global

```
var pair = (function() { 
  var T;
  var main = function() { 
    alert('This is ' + T);
  };
  var caller = function() { 
    T = 'me';
    main();
  };
  return { 'main': main, 'caller': caller}
})();

pair.main(); // Call main
pair.caller(); // Call caller
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the object of the variable `T` to the function main and access it via `this`

```
main = function() {
   alert('This is ' + this);
}

caller = function() {
   var T = 'me';
   main.call(T);
}

caller();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recall for three options:

- make T global;
- make a getter in caller object and use it to get the value
- pass T as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var T = '';
main = function() {
  alert('This is ' + T);
}

caller = function() {
  T = 'me';
  main();
}

caller();
```