# Dynamic onclick function assignment with dynamic parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
document.getElementById('img'+i).onclick = function(){popup_show('popup',array_msg[i]+'|||'+date('Y-m-d',strtotime(lec_date))+'-==-'+str_view_forConflict, 'AddEditSchedule;;popup_drag2;;EditSched;;'+String(array_msg_id[3])+';;view', 'popup_drag', 'popup_exit', 'screen-center', 0, 0);};
```

...but when I click on the image, the data of `array_msg[i]` is the last data of the loop, meaning the index is the length of the loop. I use IE for this.

Please give me an idea on how to do this. In FF, it works fine because I use `setAttribute`.

@bobince

```
document.getElementById('img'+i).onclick= popup_show.bind(window, 'popup',array_msg[i]+'|||'+date('Y-m-d',strtotime(lec_date))+'-==-'+str_view_forConflict,'AddEditSchedule;;popup_drag2;;EditSched;;'+array_msg_id[3]+';;view','popup_drag', 'popup_exit', 'screen-center', 0, 0    ); 
                if (!('bind' in Function.prototype)) {
                    Function.prototype.bind= function(owner) {
                        var that= this;
                        var args= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                        return function() {
                            return that.apply(owner,
                                args.length===0? arguments : arguments.length===0? args :
                                args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))
                            );
                        };
                    };
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treby, this is cleaned up version of your answer.  The additional anonymous anonymous function that you added isn't necessary.

```
for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById(i + '05').onclick = (function(tmp) {
    return function() { 
      popup_show(
        "popup", 
        array_msg[tmp] + '|||' + date('Y-m-d', strtotime(lec_date)) + '-==-' + str_view_forConflict, 
        "AddEditSchedule;;popup_drag2;;EditSched;;" + String(array_msg_id[3]) + ";;view", 
        "popup_drag", "popup_exit", "screen-center", 0, 0
      );
    };
  })(i);
}
```

Edited to fix closure issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [closure](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48). It would help if you provided the loop code as well as the code that is executed in the loop, but assuming you have a standard `for` loop iterating through an array, the following code should work:

```
for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++)
{
    (function(i) {
        document.getElementById("img" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {
            popup_show("popup", array_msg[i] + "|||" + date("Y-m-d", strtotime(lec_date)) + "-==-" + str_view_forConflict, "AddEditSchedule;;popup_drag2;;EditSched;;" + String(array_msg_id[3]) + ";;view", "popup_drag", "popup_exit", "screen-center", 0, 0);
        }, false);
    })(i);
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using `setAttribute` in Firefox. Instead, use [`element.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) or, preferably, [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), which allows you to add multiple functions to be called when an event fires and thus this plays nicely with other code (if two bits of code assign a function to, say, a click event in the form `element.onclick = function() { ...`, then the second assignment overrides the first—not good). I've used `element.addEventListener` in my code example above.

Comment: what do you suggest to use then? .onclick??

Comment: Yes. `onclick` is cross-browser compatible going back over a decade. It's actually IE, not Firefox, that gets `setAttribute` wrong; either way you should generally never use `setAttribute` in an HTML document. (It still has uses in XML.)

Comment: I would definitely recommend using `onclick` rather than `setAttribute`, but these days, `onclick` is also a bit dated. I would recommend using `addEventListener` instead. More information about `addEventListener` and its IE equivalent (`attachEvent`) can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.

Comment: it says:

Webpage error details
Timestamp: Fri, 8 Jan 2010 06:49:44 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 348
Char: 9
Code: 0

Comment: @Treby: Which browser are you testing it in?

Comment: Internet Explorer  and you loop is kinda weird. "l = array.length; i < l" i don't get this?

Comment: @Treby: It is a performance best-practice. It's very inefficient to constantly look up the `length` property of an array every loop iteration, so we cache the length of the array in a variable, `l`, and use this whenever we need to access the array's length during the loop.

Comment: @Treby: The above code doesn't take IE into account at all—try testing it in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, or another standards-compliant browser...

Comment: +1 for closure, -1 for browser dependency. `element.onclick` may be a bit dated, but it works in all browsers, and it's shorter.  The only problem with it is it only allows for one callback per event type.  However, this isn't always a problem, and at least not in this case.  See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Answer (score 2):

You've hit the loop-variable-closure problem. This is a very common gotcha in C-style languages with closures, such as JavaScript and Python. See the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables) for a solution involving binding the loop variables in a second closure.

A slightly less nested solution is to use `function.bind()`:

```
for (var i= 0; i<something.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img'+i).onclick= popup_show.bind(window, 'popup',
        array_msg[i]+'|||'+date('Y-m-d',strtotime(lec_date))+'-==-'+str_view_forConflict,
        'AddEditSchedule;;popup_drag2;;EditSched;;'+array_msg_id[3]+';;view',
        'popup_drag', 'popup_exit', 'screen-center', 0, 0
    );
}
```

however since this method is an ECMAScript Fifth Edition feature not supported by most browsers yet it needs a little help — see the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748941/setattribute-onclick-and-cross-browser-compatability#749253) for a backwards-compatible implementation.

Comment: i have an error 
error details
Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 261
Char: 3
Code: 0

line 261 pertains to
document.getElementById(;popup_drag;)['target']   = id;

Comment: Impossible to say without the code of that function really, but it's looking for an element with a given ID and not finding it. I don't know what the semicolons are doing there; if there were really like that in your source code that would be a syntax error and wouldn't run at all.

Comment: check out my question: this what i did

Comment: I mean that function where it is going wrong — the error is occurring inside another function, presumably `popup_show`. Anyway, you will need the code that defines `function.bind` to go *before* the loop that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Closures. You need to use JavaScript Closures. See if answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/variables-in-anonymous-functions-can-someone-explain-the-following) help.

Answer (score -1):

Working Answer:

```
var closures = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  closures[i] = (function(tmp) {
        return function() {
        document.getElementById(tmp + '05').onclick = function(){popup_show("popup", array_msg[tmp]+'|||'+date('Y-m-d',strtotime(lec_date))+'-==-'+str_view_forConflict, "AddEditSchedule;;popup_drag2;;EditSched;;"+ String(array_msg_id[3]) +";;view", "popup_drag", "popup_exit", "screen-center", 0, 0)};
        };
})(i);

  closures[i]();
}
```

Thanks to [Steve Harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48492/steve-harrison) Answer. I got an idea to wrap around it

Comment: If the question is answered, mark it as such.  A note on the code: there's likely not a reason to save references to each closure.  See my answer for a revised version of what you have.