# Global Javascript Event Handling Object Context

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events, objectcontext

I have the following problem in event handlers in Javascript. I've got an object that has a `mousemove` event handler like so:

```
function MyObject(){ }
function MyObject.prototype = {

    currentMousePosition: null,
    onMouseMove: function(ev){
       this.currentMousePosition = this.getCoordinates(ev);
    },
    getCoordinates: function(ev){
        if (ev.pageX || ev.pageY)
            return { x: ev.pageX, y: ev.pageY };

        return { x: ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft, y: ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - document.body.clientTop };
    }

};
```

The problem I'm trying to solve resolves around object context. Within my `onMouseMove` function it assigns the `currentMousePosition` property. Naturally this won't work because it's a static function handling the `mousemove` event.

What I'm looking for is a technique/method to pass an object context in with my event handler. The best example that I can think of is the Google Maps API function `GEvent.bind()`.
With it you can pass the object with the function you want to fire on the specified event. I'm essentially looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, many people do this with an explicit closure:

```
var myobject= new MyObject();
element.onmousemove= function() {
    myobject.onMouseMove();
};
```

But in the future, you'll do it with the ECMAScript Fifth Edition method `function.bind`:

```
element.onmousemove= myobject.onMouseMove.bind(myobject);
```

(Any further arguments passed to `function.bind` are prepended to the argument list of the target function when called.)

Until browsers all support `function.bind` natively, you can hack support in yourself using prototypes and closures. See the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748941/setattribute-onclick-and-cross-browser-compatability#749253) for an example implementation.

```
document.body.scrollLeft
```

It's only `document.body` if you are in IE Quirks Mode. You don't want to be in Quirks Mode. With a Standards Mode doctype, it's `document.documentElement` instead. So if you need to support different pages that might use either of the modes, or you still need to support IE5 for some reason (let's hope not):

```
var viewport= document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'? document.documentElement : document.body;
return {x: ev.clientX+viewport.scrollLeft, y: ev.clientY+viewport.scrollTop};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a wrapper function that calls your handler on the correct context.

For example:

```
addHandler(function(ev) { someObject.onMouseMove(ev); });
```