# Action Script: When binding event listeners in an automated way, only the last one from the list becomes functional..?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, automation, addeventlistener, event-listener

Here is piece of code:

```
protected function handleTriggers(raw:Object) : void
{
    var name:String, value:String, map:Object;

    map = {
            'onclick':      MouseEvent.CLICK,
            'ondblclick':   MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,
            'onmousedown':  MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,
            'onmouseup':    MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,
            'onmouseleave': MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,
            'onrollout':    MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,
            'onmouseenter': MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, 
            'onrollover':   MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,
            'onmouseover':  MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,
            'onmouseout':   MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,
            'onmousemove':  MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE
    };

    for (name in raw) 
    {
        value = raw[name];
        if (name in map) {
            var cloneValue:String = value;
            object.addEventListener(map[name], function(event:* = null) : void {
                execute(cloneValue, event); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

***object*** is generic DisplayObject and ***raw*** object contains series of onclick, onmouseover, etc event triggers. It was meant that I could attach event listeners automatically following the properties of that raw object. And it seems like it works, as I indeed can see some listener Functions in *listeners* property of the DisplayObject and their number corresponds to the number of triggers. But later when everything is put on stage, only the last event handler gets triggered.

Anyone any idea why that could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is similar to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422784/how-to-fix-closure-problem-in-actionscript-3-as3) Because you add an inline function as eventlistener the `clonevalue` has always the value of the last value in `raw`.

I think this should work (untested):

```
object.addEventListener(map[name], function(cloneValue : String) : Function {
    return function(event:* = null) : void {
         execute(cloneValue, event);
    };
})(cloneValue);
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I got the point, so I just moved the addEventListener logic to a separate function and it worked. Thanks. If you edit your response or confirm it, I will accept it as the proper one.

Comment: i forgot to invoke the function with cloneValue as param ;) now it should work...