# AS3 "for each" array issue

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to create a system that displays the name of the button that you press.
The button names are put into an array, however it only recognized the last item entered into the array.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var items:Array = [a, b, c]; //The name of each button

for each(var index in items) 
{
    index.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
}

function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(index.name); //Should display the name of any of the buttons clicked.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should trace the `currentTarget` name:

```
var items:Array = [a, b, c]; //The name of each button

for each(var index in items) {
    index.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
}

function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(event.currentTarget.name); //Should display the name of any of the buttons clicked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `index` variable created here - and `mouseClickHandler` function, obviously, works with its current value only. If you need to refer to specific values (given at each loop step), you need to localize them in one way or another:

```
function generateClickHandler(index:someType) {
  return function(event:MouseEvent):void { trace(index.name); }
}

...    
for each(var index in items) 
{
    index.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generateClickHandler(index);
}
```

I'd suggest checking this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422784/how-to-fix-closure-problem-in-actionscript-3-as3) as well.